# Reboot loop trying to install 14.04.2 amd64 on new ASUS A88XM-A

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, uefi, amd-processor

This system is brand new with no OS.

- mobo: A88XM-A with bios version 2102 x64
- CPU: AMD A10-7700K
- GPU: Radeon R7
- Plus 8GB RAM, 1TB HD, SATA DVD R/W etc.

Trying to install ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso; DVD itself checks out OK.

On DVD boot I don't get CD welcome page.
Get small logo OK, keystroke brings up advanced welcome page OK.
Ran memory test Memtest86 v4.20, graphics works.
Ran disk test, no graphics, reboots straight away.

If I enable CSM in the BIOS boot settings, when I select Try from advanced welcome page I see a continual loop:

- ASUS splash screen
- small logo at bottom

with blank screens in between, no Ubuntu loading dots ever seen.

If I disable CSM to allow UEFI boot, I get the GRUB menu and select Try and then see:

- ASUS splash screen
- back to GRUB menu

with blank screens in between, no Ubuntu loading dots ever seen.

I have tried various boot options from advanced welcome page based on what I have read on the forums and bug reports about AMD + 14.04 install problems:

- disable ACPI
- disable APIC
- nomodeset
- radeon.dpm=0

but no difference with any of these, nothing works.

Has anyone succeeded with this particular hardware and software combination?

My next step will be to try 14.10 as it seems the problem is with the 3.13 kernel, though I would rather go with LTS.

Comment: Currently installing Ubuntu 14.10 amd64 ... yay! after 3 days not even managing to load 14.04. Guess the 3.13 kernel was the killer. I had to reset the bios (load optimised defaults) to clear all the options I had tried, then Try It load 14.10 first time, no problems seen so far.

Comment: One week later and Ubuntu 14.10 working fine. So maybe that is the "solution" to installing 14.04 on this hardware combination ... don't do it ...

Comment: Now upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 amd64 and everything still good.